# Evaluate the summation $E= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k\,e^{-G}(1-e^{-G})^{k-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How would you evaluate the following summation?

\begin{equation*}
  E= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k\,e^{-G}(1-e^{-G})^{k-1} 
\end{equation*}

Comment: What is $G$? Is it any constant?

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! This question is missing context and will be closed unless vastly improved via [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4189823/edit). Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). In particular, your question should mention why you are interested in this problem and what your own efforts to approach it have been so far.

Comment: G  is the Poisson rate of transmitted frames in the Slotted Aloha system per frame time, hence it is a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, take the $e^{-G}$ term out.

Evaluate the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1 - e^{-G})^{k-1}$ which is geometric to be $e^{G}$

Notice that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k(1 - e^{-G})^{k-1} = e^{G} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k(1 - e^{-G})^{k-2} = e^{G} + (1 - e^{-G})^{-1} e^{G} + (1-e^{-G})^{-2} e^{G} + ...$ which is $e^{G} * e^{G} = e^{2G}$

Multiplying the $e^{-G}$ term back in, you arrive at the result: E = $e^{G}$

Comment: [Please don't answer PSQs](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standard).

Answer (score 2):

I really can't remember when or where I learnt this trick but
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty kr^{k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{d}{dr}r^k = \frac{d}{dr}\sum_{k=1}^\infty r^k 
$$
now can you convert your problem to the above.

Comment: [Please don't answer PSQs](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).